# How to populate a textarea(say id1) when user types in a different textarea(say id2) using php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have 2 textarea html elements say id1 and id2. When I type in id1 the content of id1 should also be displayed in id2.
Can anyone suggest me php code or jquery plugin or javascript to complete this process ?

Thanking in Advance
Girish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way how to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tb1').keyup(function(){
        var content = $('.tb1').val();
        $('.tb2').val(content);
    });
});
```

And HTML:

```
<textarea name="Text1" class="tb1" ></textarea>
<textarea name="Text2" class="tb2" ></textarea>
```

[**Working example at jsfiddle.net.**](http://jsfiddle.net/balron/qyaRs/)

Comment: I changed the code to match textarea requirement. I did miss that at first. I have also added working example.

Comment: hi dampe thanks. Can u help me with this new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611158/how-to-add-and-combine-text-value-of-2-textarea-elements-and-populate-the-combine

Answer (score 0):

like this

the html

```
<input type="text" id="box_1" />
<input type="text" id="box_2" />
```

the jQuery

```
$("#box_1").change(function(){
   $('#box_2').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/EjmtY/

HTML:

```
<textarea id='id1'></textarea>
<textarea id='id2'></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#id1').keyup(function(){
    $('#id2').val($(this).val())
})
```