# How to add and combine text value of 2 textarea elements and populate the combined text in a third textarea using JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, textarea

Hi
I have 3 textarea elements say tb1,tb2 and tb3. The text values of tb2 and tb3 should get populated in tb1 as soon as i start typing in tb2 or tb3.The format in which text should appear in tb1 is  . The space between is important.
Can anyone suggest me javascript for this purpose ?
Thanking in Advance
Girish

Comment: You want us to write you code? It is question-answer service, not task-implementation service. You should have a question - what is not clear to you.

Comment: ok i will make sure about it next time

Answer (score 3):

```
$($$('#tb2, #tb3')).keyup(function(){
    var value = $('#tb2').val() + ' ' + $('#tb3').val();
    value = jQuery.trim(value);
    $('#tb1').val(value);
});
```